# Async array.map returning undefined

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, array.prototype.map, node-fetch

I can't quite work out why my async map fetch function returns an array of undefined values or "Promise {  }" no matter what I do. My getImageRef function works (I've tried to simplify it by stripping some bits out) but how do I get it to return values to the Promise.all in formatBooks?

```
const inventory = [
    {
    "isbn":"foo",
    "title":"bar",
    "imageURL":"http://web.com/image.jpg"
    }
]
const getImageRef = async book => { //this part works on its own
  await fetch(book.imageURL)  
    .then(res => res.buffer())
    .then(buffer => client.assets.upload('image', buffer))
    .then(assetDocument => {
      let book.imageRef = assetDocument._id
      return book
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.error('Error: ' + book.image)
      return book
    })
  }

async function formatBooks (inventory) {

  await Promise.all(inventory.map(async book => {
        const docs = await getImageRef(book) // 'docs' returns as undefined

      })
  ).then(function(docs) {   
    uploadBooks(docs)
  })
}
function uploadBooks (documents) {   
  console.log(documents)
}
formatBooks(data)
```

Comment: Your `.map` callback doesn't return anything, so your `inventory.map` call just produces an array of promises that all resolve to `undefoned`.

Comment: you need to return the promises or awaited(resolved) values, also use `await` or `.then` chains.

Comment: Try changing `await fetch(book.imageURL)` to `return fetch(book.imageURL)` in the `getImageRef()` function. That way, `docs` should be equal to whatever `getImageRef()` returns

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek wow that got it working! I have been looking all over and haven't come across that syntax before. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Posted as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
await fetch(book.imageURL)
```

to

```
return fetch(book.imageURL)
```

in the `getImageRef()` function.

That way, `docs` will be equal to whatever `getImageRef()` returns. It's required because `await` itself does not cause the whole `getImageRef()` function to return anything. The function returns whatever comes after the `return` keyword or `undefined` if it's not provided - and that's where the `undefined` comes from in your case.